# Java ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arrays

I can't seem to figure out why java is throwing an array index out of bounds exception here:

```
package for_John;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class merge { 
    public static void addArray(int iid[], String phen[]){ 
        int i=0;
        int j=0; 
        int x=0; 

        for(x=0; x<5; x++) {    
            while(iid[i] == iid[++i] && i <= phen.length){
                i=i+1;
            }

            System.out.println(Arrays.toString((Arrays.copyOfRange(phen, j, i))));
            j=i;
            i=i+1;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int iid[]={1,1,1,3,3,3,3,4,4,6,6,7,7,7,8,8};
        String phen[]={"a","b","c","w","n","f","h","g","y","u","u","l","l","l","k","p"}; 
        addArray(iid, phen);
    }
}
```

The output looks good up until the exception:

```
      Output: [a, b, c]
              [w, n, f, h]
              [g, y]
              [u, u]

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
at for_John.merge.addArray(merge.java:12)
at for_John.merge.main(merge.java:22)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Guarantee it's that crazy while loop condition you have.

Comment: **First letter** of a Class name, should be in **captal**

Comment: A lot of problems with the conventions and indentation, may have extra braces. Might want to fix that first.

Comment: And I would like to give more general recommendations about your code.
1. Give more descriptive names to variables - it is totally unclear what do iid, phen, x mean
2. Generally loop inside a loop is bad. You should consider making separate method for inner loop. Name that method carefully - it will help to read the code.
3. Maybe you should read some literature about code style and refactoring. Probably Martin Fowler "Clean Code".
I hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check if `i` is greater or equals `iid.length` before calling `iid[++i]`.

You can do it like:

```
while (iid[i] == iid[++i] && i <= phen.length) {
            i = i + 1;
            if (i + 1 >= iid.length) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: just added:  if (i<=phen.length) in front of the for statement but still got the same error